# pymysql.connect command crash the python shell on Windows

Tags: python, windows, crash, maya, pymysql

Starting this month (August 2021) I have this issue on a computer after a fresh Windows 10 Professional installation, fun fact identical machines prepared earlier still working fine as always been.

Python 2.7.10 + pymysql 0.6.6 (already tried also the 0.10 release)

Just running the most simple connection to a mySql database like:

`connection = pymysql.connect(host='myHostname', user='myUserName', password='myPassword', db='databaseName', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)`

the python shell on the affected machine closing without any error or warning while on other two hundred machines this call still working fine without any trouble.

Any idea or suggestion for this weird fact?

Comment: Python 2.7.18 fix the issue, of course I know Python 2.7 reached the end of life, but unfortunatelly the 2.7.11 is the only one usable inside the Autodesk Maya version that we are using in production right now, so I would like to find the reason and hopefully the eventual solution for this specific environment, fun fact this doesn't happen on all machines freshly formatted but only for one with a specific hardware... It could be the processor the root of the issue? It's too weird...

Comment: After further investigations seems like it is not the Windows build\installation the culprit but instead the specific processor generation: 11th Gen Intel Core i9-11900K     https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-forum/faulting-module-crash/m-p/10562895#M89937

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:

https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012750300-Q100573-Katana-Mari-and-Nuke-can-fail-to-launch-with-a-10th-or-11th-Generation-Intel-CPU

It is a bug coming from OpenSSL on Windows only on 10 and 11 gen of Intel cpu (pymysql and python wasn't the issue):

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/openssl-sha-crash-bug-requires-application-update.html